# Unique trend Curve Fitting

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, smoothing

I have data like this:

```
x = np.array([   0.  ,    3.  ,    3.3 ,   10.  ,   18.  ,   43.  ,   80.  ,
            120.  ,  165.  ,  210.  ,  260.  ,  310.  ,  360.  ,  410.  ,
            460.  ,  510.  ,  560.  ,  610.  ,  660.  ,  710.  ,  760.  ,
            809.5 ,  859.  ,  908.5 ,  958.  , 1007.5 , 1057.  , 1106.5 ,
            1156.  , 1205.5 , 1255.  , 1304.5 , 1354.  , 1403.5 , 1453.  ,
            1502.5 , 1552.  , 1601.5 , 1651.  , 1700.5 , 1750.  , 1799.5 ,
            1849.  , 1898.5 , 1948.  , 1997.5 , 2047.  , 2096.5 , 2146.  ,
            2195.5 , 2245.  , 2294.5 , 2344.  , 2393.5 , 2443.  , 2492.5 ,
            2542.  , 2591.5 , 2640.  , 2690.  , 2740.  , 2789.67, 2839.33,
            2891.5 ])
y = array([ 1.45  ,  1.65  ,  5.8   ,  6.8   ,  8.0355,  8.0379,  8.04  ,
           8.0505,  8.175 ,  8.3007,  8.4822,  8.665 ,  8.8476,  9.0302,
           9.528 ,  9.6962,  9.864 , 10.032 , 10.2   , 10.9222, 11.0553,
           11.1355, 11.2228, 11.3068, 11.3897, 11.4704, 11.5493, 11.6265,
           11.702 , 11.7768, 11.8491, 11.9208, 11.9891, 12.0571, 12.1247,
           12.1912, 12.2558, 12.3181, 12.3813, 12.4427, 12.503 , 12.5638,
           12.6226, 12.6807, 12.7384, 12.7956, 12.8524, 12.9093, 12.9663,
           13.0226, 13.0786, 13.1337, 13.1895, 13.2465, 13.3017, 13.3584,
           13.4156, 13.4741, 13.5311, 13.5899, 13.6498, 13.6533, 13.657 ,
           13.6601])
```

and look like this :

[image]

I need to make curve fitting for this trend. Iam using Moving Average for smoothing and look like this:

[image]

where the magenta color is the MA, and Iam using polynomial (5th Ordo) and look like this:

[image]

where the blue is the result of the polynomial. I have try higher ordo, but the result getting worst. How can I get a result where first point at (0,0) and look like this (like black curve)?

[image]

This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
def movingaverage(interval, window_size):
     window= np.ones(int(window_size))/float(window_size)
     print(window)
     return np.convolve(interval, window, 'same')
y_av = movingaverage(y, 2)
X = np.arange(0,np.max(x),30).ravel()
yinter = interpolate.interp1d(x,y_av)(X)
z = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y_av,5))
Y = z(X)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(xm,ym,'*-r')
plt.plot(xm,y_av,'.-m')
plt.plot(X,Y,'*-b')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you should use your analytical function (with parameters) based on some assumption (not only polynomial functions). You can use `curve_fit` form `scipy.optimize` to find the unknown parameters of your analytic function that best fit your input data.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# your analytical function (theoretical function) with parameters: a, b (or more)
def your_analytical_func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.log(x + b) # this is just for example 
# or using anonymous (lambda) function
# your_analytical_func = lambda x, a, b: a * np.log(x + b)


# Fit for the parameters a, b (or more) of the function your_analytical_func:
popt, pcov = curve_fit(your_analytical_func, x, y)

plt.plot(x, y, 'r.', label='incoming data')
plt.plot(x, your_analytical_func(x, *popt), '-', color="black", label='fit: your_analytical_func(x, a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f)' % tuple(popt))
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You for your answer, so helpful. I have a question, can I get function automatically for each data set (more than 100)?

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand your question. What do you mean "get function automatically"? Typically, in order to fit, some guess is needed (from some theory). So, for example, you can use one function with parameters (for example, polynomial function) that are different for each set.